# Is 1 divided by 3 equal to 0.333...?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions, decimal-expansion

I have been taught that $\frac{1}{3}$ is `0.333...`. However, I believe that this is not true, as 1/3 cannot actually be represented in base ten; even if you had infinite threes, as `0.333...` is supposed to represent, it would not be exactly equal to 1/3, as 10 is not divisible by 3.

```
0.333... = 3/10 + 3/100 + 3/1000...
```

This occured to me while I  discussion on one of Zeno's Paradoxes. We were talking about one potential solution to the race between Achilles and the Tortoise, one of Zeno's Paradoxes. The solution stated that it would take Achilles $11\frac{1}{3}$ seconds to pass the tortoise, as `0.111... = 1/9`. However, this isn't that case, as, no matter how many ones you add, `0.111...` will never equal precisely $\frac{1}{9}$.

Could you tell me if this is valid, and if not, why not? Thanks!

I'm not arguing that $0.333...$ isn't the closest that we can get in base 10; rather, I am arguing that, in base 10, we cannot accurately represent $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics) |
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics). Your reasoning is not valid; you do not know what "0.333..." *means* in the first place. It is a perfectly sensible question that has been asked time and again by those not in the know about limits and analysis, though.

Comment: What is your understanding of the notation, $0.333\dots$?

Comment: The fact that 10 is not divisible by 3 means that 1/3 will have 2 or more digits after dot.

Comment: $0.11111\ldots$ is exactly $1/9$

Comment: Also, did you know that $0.9999\ldots = 1$?

Comment: This has to be a duplicate.

Comment: Zeno is wrong (as are you), as classical mechanics (and real numbers) exist in a continuum. The erroneous arguments are based on a system with infinitesimals.

Comment: Can you name a number that's between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $0.333 \ldots$ without being equal to either of them?

Comment: @yatima2975 good point there.

Comment: @OrangeDog Why do you say Zeno was wrong? That was not his argument, as he only proposed the paradox.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Careful, the arguments are erroneous but Zeno himself was not wrong.  His intention was to show that geometers of the time were being sloppy in their treatment of infinities by showing how their methods resulted in absurdities.

Comment: This question actually demonstrates extraordinary thought. The reason many people are offended by "$0.999...=1$" is that they confuse (as they were brought up to confuse) a number with the way it is represented, i.e., as a decimal. They therefore assume $0.999...\neq 1$ because, as infinite strings of digits, indeed they are different. Almost nobody doubts $1/3=0.333...$ because what else could $1/3$ be?

Comment: @yatima2975 No, because $0.333...$ is a close as we can get in base 10. In base 3, $\frac{1}{3}$ would be $0.1$, and `3 * 0.1 = 1` (base 3). To my understanding, it is not the same with base 10.

Comment: In base 3, that is trivial, unlike in base 10.

Comment: @XanderHenderson [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157976/rigorous-proof-that-frac13-0-333-ldots) is also related.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is a simple reasoning that $1/3=0.3333...$.

Lets denote $0.333333......$ by $x$. Then

$$x=0.33333.....$$
$$10x=3.33333...$$

Subtracting we get $9x=3$. Thus $x=\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Since $x$ was chosen as $0.3333....$ it means that $0.3333...=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Cool note: You can extend this to show that 0.9999... = 1

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher: That's actually plain wrong. Follow the question here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1/60#60 .

Comment: @Inceptio Do share, I've got the proof sitting in front of me that I'm correct from YOUR link, as well as a number of others. Set x = 0.9999 and repeat the process outlined above.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher Actually I adapted the proof of $0.999999...=1$ for this case ;)

Comment: @Inceptio All the proofs there explain why what GM said is RIGHT ;)

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher: $0.9999...=1$, this isn't the way(Multiply by 3) you prove it though..

Comment: @Inceptio: they are multiplying by $10$, not $3$.

Comment: @Inceptio: In either this proof or the $.999\ldots = 1$ proof they multiply by $10$, not by $3$.

Comment: @robjohn:  $0.33333..=\frac{1}{3}$, but you just can't **multiply $3$** on both sides to get $.999..=1$ .

Comment: I don't think that's what GraphicsMuncher meant by "extend".  I think they meant that the same argument can be used to show that for any single digit $a$ the decimal $.aaa\ldots$ is $\frac{a}{9}$.

Comment: All this assumes that we can safely perform _certain_ operations on infinite decimals (not all, since $1-0.9999\ldots$ would probably get us confused) without knowing about limits, and therefore not knowing how infinite decimals are defined. This is an illusion.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: any of this without knowledge of limits would be gibberish. This is often where the confusion lies.

Comment: The trick in this is that 10 x 0.3... is not 3.3... it is 3.3... with a 0 on the end ;)

Comment: PLEASE nobody else upvote this answer! It's perfect right now.

Answer (score 16):

You can find the sum of $\frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{100} + \frac{3}{1000} + \cdots$ using the formula of sum of infinite geometric progression.

$$a_1 = \frac{3}{10}$$

$$r=\frac{1}{10}$$

$$\sum =\frac{a_1}{1-r}=\frac{3}{10}\times\frac{10}{9} =\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 10):

The problematic part of the question is "no matter how many ones you add, `0.111...` will never equal precisely 1/9."

In this (imprecise) context $0.111\ldots$ is an infinite sequence of ones; the sequence of ones does not terminate, so there is no place at which to add another one; each one is already followed by another one. Thus, $10\times0.111\ldots=1.111\ldots$ is precise. Therefore, $9\times0.111\ldots=1.000\ldots=1$ is precise, and $0.111\ldots=1/9$.

I say "imprecise" because we also say $\pi=3.14159\dots$ where `...` there means an unspecified sequence of digits following. A more precise way of writing what, in the context of this question, we mean by $0.111\dots$ is $0.\overline{1}$ where the group of digits under the bar is to be repeated without end.

In this question, $0.333\ldots=0.\overline{3}$, and just as above, $10\times0.\overline{3}=3.\overline{3}$, and therefore, $9\times0.\overline{3}=3.\overline{0}=3$, which means $0.\overline{3}=3/9=1/3$.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't follow the thread here [Is it true that $0.999999999\ldots = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1/60#60).

Well, $\frac{1}{3}=0.33333\ldots$

You can use $1$.Geometric Progression. Or $2$. The one **N.S** suggested.

Comment: $\dfrac13 \neq 0.33333$

Comment: @Marvis: Fine, now? :)

Comment: You may want to use `\ldots` inside math mode to display $\ldots$ . I have edited your post now.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to show that $0.999\ldots=1$.

I give here a proof and tou can see  [Does .99999... = 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1/60#60)
for another proofs. We have
$$0.999\ldots\leq 1\leq 0.999\ldots+\frac{1}{10^n},\, \forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$
so by passing at limit ($n\to\infty$) we find
$$0.999\ldots\leq1\leq 0.999\ldots$$
which allows us to conclude.

Answer (score -1):

The following uses the limiting concept to prove that $0.33333=\frac{1}{3}$

$$3+0.33333...=\sum_{i=0}^N\frac{3}{10^n}\quad\text{where N}\to\infty$$
$$=3\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{1}{10^n}$$
$$=3\sum_{n=0}^N(\frac{1}{10})^n$$

Known
$$1+a^2+a^3....a^n=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$
So
$$=3\cdot \frac{(\frac{1}{10})^{N+1}-1}{\frac{1}{10}-1}$$
$$=3\cdot \frac{(\frac{1}{10})^{N+1}-1}{\frac{1-10}{10}}$$
$$=3\cdot \frac{((\frac{1}{10})^{N+1}-1)*10}{1-10}$$
$$=3\cdot \frac{(1-(\frac{1}{10})^{N+1})*10}{9}$$

Now apply the limiting concept, if $N\to\infty;(\frac{1}{10})^{N+1}\to0$
$$=3\cdot \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{(1-(\frac{1}{10})^{N+1})*10}{9}$$
$$=3\cdot \frac{10}{9}$$
$$=\frac{10}{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow 3+0.33333...=\frac{10}{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow 0.33333...=\frac{10}{3}-3$$
$$\Rightarrow 0.33333...=\frac{10-9}{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow 0.33333...=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: There is a mistake here, it is `3+0.333..` and not `1+0.333..`. You managed to correct this with another mistake near the end (tip: 1 is not equal to 9/3).

Comment: Error in your first line: $0.33333\ne\frac{1}{3}$.